# How do I apply a rolling aggregation function over a subset of the rolling data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, performance

Suppose I have a large dataset, and I want to apply a rolling operation over a long period, but only want to apply the aggregation over a small number of datapoints. Can I do this with `pandas`?

When I try to apply a slicer to the result of an aggregation function, it seems that I'm too late and the whole compuation has already happened:

```
small = 10
big = 1000
bigger = 10000000
s = pd.Series(np.arange(bigger))

%time x = s.rolling(big).mean()
%time x = s.rolling(big).mean()[:-small]
```

The output of this is:

```
CPU times: user 306 ms, sys: 162 ms, total: 467 ms
Wall time: 468 ms
CPU times: user 291 ms, sys: 127 ms, total: 418 ms
Wall time: 418 ms
```

In the above example, I had hoped for the second timed expression to run more quickly, as I only needed the aggregation to be computed over the last 10 datapoints, but it took the same amount of time as calculating it for 10 million.

What am I doing wrong here?

**In my actual scenario I'm using both `rolling` and `expanding`, so I'm looking for a solution that applies to both. Also, in my actual example `big` is nearly the same as `bigger`.**

**EDIT:** The following illustrates the performance difference of calculating a rolling mean vs a calculation without redundant calcs. It calculates the naive case, the solution by `3UqU57GnaX`, as well as a "manual" calculation. Note that the manual calculation is what I'm hoping to achieve in the general case (obviously I don't want to manually implement every aggregation function):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

small = 10
big = 10000000
bigger = 100000000
s = pd.Series(np.arange(bigger))

def adjusted_mean(current_mean, removed_element, new_element, length):
    return current_mean + (new_element - removed_element) / length

def rolling_mean_optimisation(small, big):
    current_mean = s[-big-small:-small].mean()

    return [adjusted_mean(current_mean, s.values[-big-x], s.values[-x], big) for x in range(small, 0, -1)]

%time naive = s.rolling(big).mean()[-small:]
%time answer_by_3UqU57GnaX = s[-big-small:].rolling(big).mean()[-small:]
%time manual_mean_optimisation = rolling_mean_optimisation(small, big)
```

While `3UqU57GnaX`'s answer is a big improvement over the naive case, the manual implementation is almost an order of magnitude faster still (the actual amount depends on the size of `big` vs `bigger`:

```
CPU times: user 3.31 s, sys: 1.56 s, total: 4.87 s
Wall time: 4.88 s
CPU times: user 292 ms, sys: 154 ms, total: 446 ms
Wall time: 445 ms
CPU times: user 60.3 ms, sys: 21.2 ms, total: 81.4 ms
Wall time: 81.2 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

It takes the same time since you are first applying `rolling` and `mean` over the whole series.

If you apply it on the last 10 datapoints only (`s[-10:]`)then it will be faster:

```
s[-10:].rolling(1000).mean()
```

This will give you NaN values however, since you only use the last 10 datapoints but you need 1000 datapoints for the rolling mean.

Edit: This will not gives you NaNs and should be faster:

```
s[-big-small:].rolling(big).mean()[-small:]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, and welcome to SO :). I think your answer will work well in cases when `big` << `bigger`. But what if I'm using `expanding` rather than `rolling`, and what if `big` is also very large (but `small` is still small)?

Comment: I don't think you can increase the speed much if `bigger` and `big` are the same order of magnitude, right?

Comment: Well if `big` and `bigger` are both in the order of millions, and small is `10`, then in the naiive case the cost of running a custom `agg` would be in the order of millions of times more than for 10 elements. I'm sure the real `sum` aggregator is smarter than that, but it's still more work.

Comment: What is the speed increase with my implementation (even if `big` and `bigger` are similar)?

Comment: It's about an order of magnitude, depending on how close `big` and `bigger` are. I've edited my question to show the benchmark against a manual implementation.